# Xcode 6 localization

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I'm using XCode 6 beta 4.

I have experience with localization iOS app with xCode 5, but now I can't find a way to use localized strings in code.

When I put something like `"alertMessage" = "Warning!"` in `Main.strings (English)` and then try to use `NSLocalizedString` method to get my localized string, I just get same string, which I put as a parameter.

Where should I put `"alertMessage" = "Warning!"` and others localized strings so I could use them in code? There is no `lproj` folder and no `Localizable.strings` file.

There is a screenshot of my test project:

[image]

**Updated**

I found the solution. I should open in Finder `lproj` folder (which does not appear in Xcode) in project folder and have to manually create `Localizable.strings` file, and then drop him in Xcode project.

Comment: (Actually that app is called Xcode, not xCode.)

Comment: kind of like if someone said hey martin. Which is totally different to hey Martin.